# Google Drive Sharing Dialog from a Chrome Web App

Tags: google-drive-api, google-chrome-app

I want to load the Google Drive sharing dialog from a Chrome App (described at https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-sharing).

However, since the [standard gapi javascript library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/) cannot be loaded from a chrome app, it appears I need to use the [Google API javascript client library loader for Chrome Packaged Apps](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/libraries/gapi-chrome-apps-lib).

This chrome app gapi library is currently limited to implementing gapi.auth and gapi.client.request. The drive sharing dialog requires the use of gapi.load to access the ShareClient.

```
init = function() {
    s = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient('<YOUR_APP_ID>');
    s.setItemIds(["<FILE_ID>"]);
}
window.onload = function() {
    gapi.load('drive-share', init);
}
```

Is it possible to display the Drive Sharing dialog from within a chrome app?